# PIG - Can I convert a byteArray to a tuple

Tags: java, hadoop, protocol-buffers, apache-pig

I am processing a sequence file.  Each record in the sequence file is a protobuf.

In PIG I'm loading the sequence file using elephantbird's SequenceFileLoader and ProtoBuf Converter.

So, now I can see a tuple that represents the protobuf object.  Let's say:

```
objects: {object: {id: long, name: chararray, nested-object: bytearray}....}.
```

The nested-object is another protobuf with two properties (prop1, prop2).

Now, can someone help me figure out how I can convert the nested-object's bytearray into another tuple (prop1, prop2) (not sure if tuple is the right term)?

Comment: What do you mean by tuple here and especially by **another** tuple?

Comment: @Andrey I edited the question - hope it is more clear now.

Comment: As a note, when I read `{prop1, prop2}` I see that as a bag like `{(prob1), (prop2)}` which has a schema like `B:{T:(prop:chararray)}`.  A tuple would look like `(prop1, prop2)` and have a schema like `T:(p1:chararray, p2:chararray)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way, but I solved the problem by writing a UDF following these [instructions](http://verboselogging.com/2010/03/31/writing-user-defined-functions-for-pig).

My UDF would take the DataByteArray and return a Tuple.

Then in Pig:

```
nestedObjects = FOREACH objects GENERATE MY_UDF_CONVERTER(nested_object);
```

Comment: It also may be worthwhile to see if you can just [cast the field](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#cast).

Answer (score 0):

Create [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) with our array and then feed it to converter.